# another $_POST not retrieving data from Javascript's Fetch() (but ajax does...) (solved)

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

solved: i forgot to add the data to the fetch...

i am finally taking the step to ajax & co... looked the stuff up, and wanted to go with the newer fetch mechanism, but that didn't work.... the $_POST on the server-side remained frustratingly empty.... i switched to ajax, with the same server, nearly the same code, and it works!

so i have a working solution, but still, its not satisfying to know that something that should work, doesn't... so if anyone has a solution?

let's start with the php mockup:

```
 testsave.php:
 
 <?php
   print("POST = ".print_r($_POST,true));
   print("inputstream :".file_get_contents('php://input')."\n");//maybe here??
 ?>
```

and test.php:

```
<html>
 <header>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.svg">
 </header>
 <body>
  <form  method="post" onsubmit="return withajax('testsave.php','testfield');">
   <input type="text" id="testfield"/>
   <input type="submit" value="ok"/>
  </form>
  <script> 
     function withajax(filename, fieldname)
     {
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append(fieldname, document.getElementById(fieldname).value);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", filename);
        xhr.onload = function()
        {
          document.getElementById(fieldname).value = this.response;
          console.log(this.response);
        };
        xhr.send(data);
        return false;
     }//function withajax(filename)

     function withfetch(filename, fieldname)
     {
       let data = new FormData();
       data.append(fieldname, document.getElementById(fieldname).value);
       let configObj =
       {
         method: "POST",
         //cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
         //credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
         body: data
       };
       fetch(filename,configObj) //<-- edit without adding the data, it won't work.... 
      .then(function (response) 
       {
         return response.text();
       })
      .then(function (text) 
      {
        document.getElementById(fieldname).value = text;
        console.log("response = "+text);

      })
     .catch(function (error) 
     {
             console.log("Error : "+error);
      });
      return false; 
   }//function withfetch(filename)
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

if in the onsubmit of the form i put withajax, it works, if i put withfetch, there's nothing in the $_POST in the php script...

Comment: You're not using your `configObj`. Does it work if you try `fetch(filename, configObj)`?

Comment: argh..... :banging head on keyboard: as far as stupid errors go, that one goes far :( yeah that was it... thanks! at least it stop me running circles....